# Install grunt-phonegap - Error: No compatible version found: URIjs@'^1.12.0'

Tags: cordova, dependencies, gruntjs, npm

I was trying to install grunt-phonegap

> npm install grunt-phonegap

And got this error

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/URIjs
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: URIjs@'^1.12.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.4.2","1.6.3","1.7.0","1.7.1","1.7.2","1.7.3","1.7.4","1.8.0","1.8.1","1.8.2","1.8.3","1.9.0","1.9.1","1.10.0","1.10.1","1.10.2","1.11.0","1.11.1","1.11.2","1.12.0"]
```

I've answered to my question, but it's just a temporary solution which doesn't explain the real problem.

Comment: You have an outdated npm version. It has been answered many times before, see [this](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/issues/49#issuecomment-36779628) thread for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374175/alex) mentioned in the comment, correct answer is to update npm version which supports '^' in describing versions