# npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks Issue

Tags: node.js

I got this Error:

> ERR! Error: No compatible version found: multimatch@'^0.1.0' ERR!
>   Valid install targets: ERR! ["0.1.0"] ERR!     at installTargetsError
>   (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:676:10) ERR!
>   at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:591:10 ERR!
>   at saved (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:138:7)
>   ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15) ERR! If you need help,
>   you may report this log at: ERR!
>   http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues ERR! or email it to: ERR!
>
> ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" stall" "--save-dev"
>   "load-grunt-tasks" ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\ivde\Desktop\Dropbox\Public\BA\FDL Repository\mobile FDL
>   04.10\www ERR! node -v v0.10.5

What should I do?

**Answer:** Update npm and it works

Comment: BTW, you can answer your own question as an answer.  but hopefully with details like what version you were on and updating to which version fixed it.  that helps others

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270244/install-grunt-phonegap-error-no-compatible-version-found-urijs1-12-0#comment33861412_22270244