# What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, caret, semantic-versioning

After I upgraded to the latest stable `node` and `npm`, I tried `npm install moment --save`. It saves the entry in the `package.json` with the caret `^` prefix. Previously, it was a tilde `~` prefix.

1. Why are these changes made in `npm`?
2. What is the difference between tilde `~` and caret `^`?
3. What are the advantages over previous ones?

Comment: FYI you can prevent prefixes or use a custom one by doing: `npm config set save-prefix=''`. (Stick `~` in the quotes if that's what you prefer.) I personally do this and shrinkwrap for things in production.

Comment: All the nitty gritty details of how tilde and caret work and differences: https://github.com/npm/node-semver#tilde-ranges-123-12-1

Comment: This tool is a great helper to test https://semver.npmjs.com/

Comment: [Semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) in npm and node

Comment: Docs for [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-shrinkwrap) and [package-lock.json vs npm-shrinkwrap.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#package-lockjson-vs-npm-shrinkwrapjson) #toSaveYouAGoogle (or two) -- fncomp mentions [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224#comment44548771_22343224) and tehfoo [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224#comment45166739_22345808). Also, mneumonic: `~` stays about even, `^` goes up a little higher.

Comment: I created this video to help in understanding it: https://youtu.be/3XKIs1_FpLw

Comment: I love the puzzles that developers create for eachother like "what does the tilde mean in package.json?". The best puzzles, like this one, have you coming back year after year.

Answer (score 6128, accepted):

See the [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies) and [semver docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver):

- `~version` **“Approximately equivalent to version”**, will update you to all future patch versions, without incrementing the minor version. `~1.2.3` will use releases from 1.2.3 to <1.3.0.
- `^version` **“Compatible with version”**, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. `^1.2.3` will use releases from 1.2.3 to <2.0.0.

See Comments below for exceptions, in particular [for pre-one versions, such as ^0.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json#comment53973834_22345808)

Comment: Posting here to hopefully catch people that don't quite think this through, but both ^ and ~ assumes you can trust minor and point releases from your dependencies.  If you are publishing a library and want other people to trust you, DO NOT BLINDLY ACCEPT DOWNSTREAM DEPENDENCIES. A bad dot release from your dependency can cause a chain reaction upstream, and will have people knocking at YOUR door when things go pear shaped.   This is another huge reason to use npm shrinkwrap on your production code.

Comment: You can also just do away with all the nonsense of npm prepending your versions with a `^` or a `~`. Set this if you want to have tight control over your versions:  `npm config set save-prefix=''`

Comment: @prasanthv is right: from https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-1-2-3-0-2-5-0-0-4: Caret Ranges ^1.2.3 ^0.2.5 ^0.0.4. Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions 0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X.

Comment: @jgillich in semver when you use `0.2.x`, `2` isn't a `major version`. That's why https://docs.npmjs.com used the specific words: `the left-most non-zero digit`. Also what about this case: ^0.0.4 means 0.0.4

Comment: Hat matching is broken because it wont update `^0.1.2` to `0.2.0`. The rule is: always version your package skipping the `0.x.x` version range and you'll get consistent behaviour

Comment: @FagnerBrack: The specific example you provided is correct, but generally your way of thinking is wrong. An example: let's say you have package `A` in 3 versions: `0.0.1`, `0.0.2` and `0.0.3`. There is a bug in `0.0.1` so you want to have at least `0.0.2` in your package `B`. If you write `0.0.x` you'll get `0.0.3`, which is OK. But if some other package `C` requires both `B` and `A` and additionally has constrain `"A": "<0.0.2"` you'll get `0.0.1` without showing any conflict issue, which is not what you want. Using tilde `~0.0.2` should help you avoid this issue.

Comment: @MaciejSz I'm sorry but I didn't understand. Are you saying that the behavior for `0.0.x` is different than the behavior of `~0.0.0` or that the behavior of `0.x.0` is different than the behavior of `^0.0.0`? Or are you arguing that the `0.x.0`/`^0.0.0` pattern is better than `0.0.x`/`~0.0.0` in the context you provided?

Comment: @FagnerBrack: I'm saying that when using tilde you can define minimum version number (at the least significant version number). With the `0.0.x` notation you don't have that option because **any** least significant version number will be valid.

Comment: @MaciejSz Now I understand, specifying a minimum version instead of the latest "x" is indeed a valid use case. Very good point. Although I would recommend using neither the "x" or "~" notation to ensure consistency between multiple developers.

Comment: You now have * wich updates to most recent update regardless the version.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can use [npm semver](https://semver.npmjs.com/) to calculate version ranges for a specific package.

Comment: Caret ups to latest Minor, not Major. It's `Major`, `Minor`, `Patch`, `Hotfix`.

Comment: In the `pre-5.x` npm the symbols (`~`/`^`) were affecting the downloaded dependencies during `npm install`. After `5.x` the existence of `package-lock.json` next to `package.json` prevents this. For updating project dependencies based on the rules described in this post, `npm update` can be used (which updates also `package-lock.json`), followed by commit of both `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

Comment: This is wrong. As pointed out ^ specifies to update to minor versions & patches (middle & last number), & ~ specifies to only update to patch releases (last number). "Major" is the first number in semantic versioning, specifying breaking changes, which you don't want to auto-update to. Never saw such a glaringly wrong answer with upvoted so highly on here. It's a bit concerning.

Comment: I have edited this answer to correct the explanation. Instead of complaining about a wrong answer in its comments, please DO SOMETHING about it next time!

Comment: The caret will NOT update to the most recent major version. Only minor and patch versions.

Comment: This answer is unsalvageable because it is formed around quoting nonsense. The answer from pspi is correct and should be voted up. 
The terminology is not somehow misleading. It is nonsense. If you call a dog a horse, and then you say that horses eat meat and bark you're not talking something somehow misleading.

Comment: We have an issue here folks... WHY does this have 2764 up-votes if it's misleading or incorrect?  Maybe don't hit the up-vote button unless you're 100% sure about what you're voting on seems like good practice. Ian, take it down a notch... if an answer is wrong, misleading or confusing... then it deserves discussion, instead of stepping all over each others toes with the edit link.

Comment: The links in this accepted answer are broken. The best current official documentation link is https://github.com/npm/node-semver#versions

Comment: If any NPM devs are reading this . . . in my ideal world, none of this fuzzy versioning would be allowed, because of malware risks. Any fuzzy versioning in your package.json leaves you continually trusting that the developers of your packages do not publish malware and are not hacked or otherwise tricked into doing so. See here for an example:  https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-pjwm-rvh2-c87w

Comment: AND THEN... there's also a lot of extra rules if you use `-` or `+` in the version numbers as well!  `-` means "prerelease" and has additional rules that aren't obvious, and `+` means build and has different rules?  so much fun to diagnose these!

Answer (score 1713):

I would like to add the official npmjs documentation as well which describes all methods for version specificity including the ones referred to in the question

| value | desc |
| --- | --- |
| `~version` | Approximately equivalent to version, i.e., only accept new **patch** versions See [npm semver - Tilde Ranges](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#tilde-ranges-123-12-1) |
| `^version` | Compatible with version, i.e., accept new **minor and patch** versions See [npm semver - Caret Ranges](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) |
| `version` | Must match version exactly |
| `>version` | Must be greater than version |
| `>=version` | Must be equal or greater than version |
| `<version` | Must be lesser than version |
| `<=version` | Must be equal or lesser than version |
| `1.2.x` | 1.2.0, 1.2.1, etc., but not 1.3.0 |
| `*` | Matches any version |
| `latest` | Obtains latest release |

The above list is not exhaustive. Other version specifiers include GitHub urls and GitHub user repo's, local paths and packages with specific npm tags

#### Official Docs

- [npm docs > package.json > dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies)
- [npm docs > semver > versions](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/semver#versions)
- [semver (7)](http://semver.org/)

Comment: It is also possible to specify an exact range of versions, like `1.2.0 || >=1.2.2 <1.3.0`: Exactly 1.2.0, or everything from 1.2.2 to 1.3.0 (inclusive), but not 1.2.1, or 1.3.1 and above, and also not 1.1.x and below.

Comment: A more specific link form the above -> https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Comment: `"Approximately equivalent to version"` and `"Compatible with version"` are such frustratingly non-specific ways to describe ~ and ^ behavior.  Thank you @jgillich for providing an actual answer!

Comment: Another resource : https://nodejs.dev/learn/semantic-versioning-using-npm

Comment: Is `latest` recommend for debs that never depend on versions? Does the question makes sense at all..

Comment: @Timo "deps that never depend on versions" probably don't exist. You can have deps that don't **currently** depend on versions, but future versions of the dependency are not guaranteed to be backwards compatible so unless you own the dependency as well as the application it's a safe bet that eventually 'latest' won't work. To me it seems the best use for a 'latest' specifier is during early development, proof-of-concepts, or for short term projects that will not be maintained long term.

Comment: So is `~1.2.0` 100% equivalent to `1.2.x`? 
Because `1.2.x` is a lot easier to understand!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver In that case, with a patch version of `0`, yes they are equivalent. But if you had, for example, `~1.2.3`, that's equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <1.3.0`, whereas `1.2.x` would be equivalent to `>=1.2.0 <1.3.0` --- essentially the `~` means _any patch version greater than or equal to the one specified_, whereas the `x` in that position means _any number_. Full syntax is defined here: https://github.com/npm/node-semver#advanced-range-syntax

Answer (score 936):

The package manager [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) allows installing a newer package version than the one specified. 
Using tilde (`~`) gives you bug-fix releases, while caret (`^`) in addition gives you backward-compatible new functionality.

The problem is that old versions usually don't receive bug fixes, so npm uses caret (`^`) as the default for `--save`.

[image: SemVer table]

Source: ["SemVer explained - why there's a caret (^) in my package.json?"](http://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/).

**Note** that the rules apply to versions above 1.0.0. Not every project follows semantic versioning. 
For versions 0.x.x the caret allows only *patch* updates, i.e., it behaves the same as the tilde. 
See ["Caret Ranges"](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004).

Here's a visual explanation of the concepts:

> [image: semver diagram]

Source: ["Semantic Versioning Cheatsheet"](http://bytearcher.com/goodies/semantic-versioning-cheatsheet).

Comment: What about ^0.2.5? from https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-1-2-3-0-2-5-0-0-4: Caret Ranges ^1.2.3 ^0.2.5 ^0.0.4. Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions 0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X.

Comment: @rofrol any version before 1.0.0 is considered unstable and these rules don't apply

Comment: So your explanation isn't complete

Comment: @rofrol yeah, omitting for readability is good sometimes, chances of having anything below 1.0.0 for a dependency in package json are pretty low. see also 20/80 principle, is a great rule for focusing on what matters

Comment: @pspi Having versions below 1.0.0 is "unlikely"? Out of 60 we've got ~15, and most of them aren't obscure.

Comment: @DaveNewton ouch... even if the version is above 1.0.0 there are no guarantees that the project is following semver, though

Comment: I like this answer, except the `3.*.*` in the table seems confusing. It implies that 3.8.8 could satisfy the `^3.9.2`. It would not

Answer (score 153):

### Semver

```
<major>.<minor>.<patch>-beta.<beta> == 1.2.3-beta.2
```

- Use [npm semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/) for testing. Although the explanations for ^ (include everything greater than a particular version in the same major range) and ~ (include everything greater than a particular version in the same minor range) aren't a 100% correct, the calculator seems to work fine.
- Alternatively, use [SemVer Check](http://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/) instead, which doesn't require you to pick a package and also offers explanations.

### Allow or disallow changes

- Pin version: `1.2.3`.
- Use `^` (like head). Allows updates at the second non-zero level from the left: `^0.2.3` means `0.2.3 <= v < 0.3`.
- Use `~` (like tail). Generally freeze right-most level or set zero if omitted:
- `~1` means `1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0`
- `~1.2` means `1.2.0 <= v < 1.3.0`.
- `~1.2.4` means `1.2.4 <= v < 1.3.0`.
- Ommit right-most level: `0.2` means `0.2 <= v < 1`. Differs from `~` because:

  - Starting omitted level version is always `0`
  - You can set starting major version without specifying sublevels.

### All (hopefully) possibilities

**Set starting major-level and allow updates upward**

```
*  or "(empty string)   any version
1                         v >= 1
```

**Freeze major-level**

```
~0 (0)            0.0 <= v < 1
0.2               0.2 <= v < 1          // Can't do that with ^ or ~ 
~1 (1, ^1)        1 <= v < 2
^1.2              1.2 <= v < 2
^1.2.3            1.2.3 <= v < 2
^1.2.3-beta.4     1.2.3-beta.4 <= v < 2
```

**Freeze minor-level**

```
^0.0 (0.0)        0 <= v < 0.1
~0.2              0.2 <= v < 0.3
~1.2              1.2 <= v < 1.3
~0.2.3 (^0.2.3)   0.2.3 <= v < 0.3
~1.2.3            1.2.3 <= v < 1.3
```

**Freeze patch-level**

```
~1.2.3-beta.4     1.2.3-beta.4 <= v < 1.2.4 (only beta or pr allowed)
^0.0.3-beta       0.0.3-beta.0 <= v < 0.0.4 or 0.0.3-pr.0 <= v < 0.0.4 (only beta or pr allowed)
^0.0.3-beta.4     0.0.3-beta.4 <= v < 0.0.4 or 0.0.3-pr.4 <= v < 0.0.4 (only beta or pr allowed)
```

**Disallow updates**

```
1.2.3             1.2.3
^0.0.3 (0.0.3)    0.0.3
```

**Notice**: Missing major, minor, patch or specifying `beta` without number, is the same as `any` for the missing level.

**Notice**: When you install a package which has `0` as major level, the update will only install new beta/pr level version! That's because `npm` sets `^` as default in `package.json` and when installed version is like `0.1.3`, it freezes all major/minor/patch levels.

- https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver
- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Comment: Telling people to avoid starting projects from 0 because library and consuming developers don't understand the system is a terrible solution. I think @asdfasdfads has much better information.

Comment: @ProLoser I just think that the system should be simplified, and we shouldn't use 0.x versions.

Comment: The use case around early lifecycle development and v0 makes a LOT of sense. Learning how v0 behaves properly has actually made me look forward to other early-lifecycle projects. It means you can have a rapidly changing API with lots of backwards incompatibility without being forced to declare your project as 1.x (aka: stable) when it really isn't.

Comment: I understand it, but I just don't like how it works with semver and qualifiers

Comment: It feels more like an opinion and shouldn't be framed as a generally accepted approach. And ^0.1.x gets patches perfectly fine.

Comment: @ProLoser But you won't get `^0.1.x` by default when installing from npm. Most likely it will be `^0.1.3` which dissalows any updates. Anyway I have dropped the advice for not using `0.*` and just added notice.

Answer (score 127):

As long as the first number ("major") is at least 1:

`~` locks major and minor numbers. It is used when you're ready to accept only bug-fixes (increments in the third number), but don't want any other changes, not even minor upgrades that add features.

`^` locks the major number only. It is used when you are willing to receive bug fixes (increments in the third number) and minor upgrades that add features but should not break existing code (increments in the second number). However you do not want changes that break existing code (increments in the first number).

In addition to that, `^` is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270244/install-grunt-phonegap-error-no-compatible-version-found-urijs1-12-0#comment33861904_22270244) by old npm versions, and should be used with caution.

So, `^` is a good default, but it's not perfect. I suggest to carefully pick and configure the semver operator that is most useful to you.

(Revised to avoid saying "fixes" and "bug-fixes" with conflicting use of "fixes", which is confusing)

Comment: not true: Caret Ranges ^1.2.3 ^0.2.5 ^0.0.4. Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions 0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-1-2-3-0-2-5-0-0-4

Comment: This answer is completely wrong (as are many other here). None of these ever fix a major number! As @rofrol said, ^ simply keeps the left most non-zero digit unchanged. ~ on the other hand allows only patch updates if the minor version is specified (e.g. ~1.2.3 or ~1.2) and allows minor updates if the minor version is not specified (e.g. ~1).

Comment: @TheBaj They mean "fix" as "define" ("fixate") rather than "adjust", so you all agree on how the major number gets handled.

Comment: Yes, this answer seemed totally backwards until I realized the answerer meant "fix" as in "to make fixed, stationary, or unchanging."

Answer (score 70):

`~` : Reasonably **close** to

```
   ~1.1.5: 1.1.0 <= accepted < 1.2.0
```

`^`: **Compatible** with

```
   ^1.1.5: 1.1.5 <= accepted < 2.0.0

   ^0.1.3: 0.1.3 <= accepted < 0.2.0

   ^0.0.4: 0.0.4 <= accepted < 0.1.0
```

Comment: @kytwb - no. In the special case of zeroth-release version numbers, the carat is equivalent to the tilde. Thus `^0.1.3` only accepts versions `0.1.x` and will not accept `0.2.0`, even though that's a minor increment. This behavior is equivalent to `~0.1.3`. The reasoning behind this behavior is due to the fact that zeroth-release packages are still considered unstable; in the words of [semver.org](http://semver.org/), #4, "anything may change at any time" (including backwards-incompatible changes).

Comment: Wouldn't that last example not allow patch upgrades either?

Answer (score 47):

**~ Tilde:**

- `~` freezes **major and minor numbers.**
- It is used when you're ready to accept bug-fixes in your dependency,
  but don't want any potentially incompatible changes.
- The tilde matches the **most recent minor version** (the middle number).
- ~1.2.3 will match all 1.2.x versions, but it will miss 1.3.0.
- Tilde (~) gives you bug fix releases

**^ Caret:**

- `^` freezes the major number only.
- It is used when you're closely watching your dependencies and are ready to quickly change your code if minor release will be incompatible.
- It will update you to the **most recent major version** (the first number).
- ^1.2.3 will match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but it will hold off on 2.0.0.
- Caret (^) gives you backwards-compatible new functionality as well.

Comment: The tilde matches the most recent patch version (the last number).
The caret matches the most most recent minor version (the middle number).

Comment: "freezes" is the best explanation.

Comment: Caret both freezes the major number and will update you to the most recent major version (the first number)? The major number is the first number, so this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 46):

`^` is 1.[any].[any] (latest minor version)
`~` is 1.2.[any] (latest patch)

A great read is [this blog post](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/98131109725/npm-2-0-0) on how semver applies to npm
and what they're doing to make it match [the semver standard](http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html)
http://blog.npmjs.org/post/98131109725/npm-2-0-0

Comment: not true: Caret Ranges ^1.2.3 ^0.2.5 ^0.0.4. Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions 0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-1-2-3-0-2-5-0-0-4

Answer (score 38):

Hat matching may be considered "broken" because it wont update `^0.1.2` to `0.2.0`. When the software is emerging use `0.x.y` versions and hat matching will only match the last varying digit (`y`). This is done on purpose. The reason is that while the software is evolving the API changes rapidly: one day you have these methods and the other day you have those methods and the old ones are gone. If you don't want to break the code for people who already are using your library you go and increment the major version: e.g. `1.0.0` -> `2.0.0` -> `3.0.0`. So, by the time your software is finally 100% done and full-featured it will be like version `11.0.0` and that doesn't look very meaningful, and actually looks confusing. If you were, on the other hand, using `0.1.x` -> `0.2.x` -> `0.3.x` versions then by the time the software is finally 100% done and full-featured it is released as version `1.0.0` and it means "This release is a long-term service one, you can proceed and use this version of the library in your production code, and the author won't change everything tomorrow, or next month, and he won't abandon the package".

The rule is: use `0.x.y` versioning when your software hasn't yet matured and release it with incrementing the middle digit when your public API changes (therefore people having `^0.1.0` won't get `0.2.0` update and it won't break their code). Then, when the software matures, release it under `1.0.0` and increment the leftmost digit each time your public API changes (therefore people having `^1.0.0` won't get `2.0.0` update and it won't break their code).

```
Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:

MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
```

Comment: This comment was ridiculously helpful and doesn't seem to be documented very well. Do you have a link to the documentation around this behavior? This answer about v0 projects has helped me a lot.

Comment: I don't have a link: I found this information too by googling and playing with npm semantic version calculator https://semver.npmjs.com/

Comment: Needs to be added to their documentation in a more formal way. I gave a talk at Sony to my engineering team because it seems to so easily get overlooked. http://slides.com/proloser/semver-v0

Answer (score 34):

**caret** `^` include everything greater than a particular version in the same major range.

**tilde** `~` include everything greater than a particular version in the same minor range.

For example, to specify acceptable version ranges up to 1.0.4, use the following syntax:

- Patch releases: 1.0 or 1.0.x or ~1.0.4
- Minor releases: 1 or 1.x or ^1.0.4
- Major releases: * or x

For more information on semantic versioning syntax, see the [npm semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/).

[image: npm semantic versions in published packages§]

More from npm documentation [About semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning)

Answer (score 32):

**Tilde (~)**

> major version is fixed, the minor version is fixed, matches any build
> number

```
"express": "~4.13.3"
```

`~4.13.3` means it will check for 4.13.x where x is anything

**Caret (^)**

> major version is fixed, matches any minor version, matches any build
> number

```
"supertest": "^3.0.0"
```

`^3.0.0` means it will check for 3.x.x where x is anything

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answer is different from [the same answer posted 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json/22365742#22365742)?

Answer (score 27):

**One liner explanation**

The standard versioning system is major.minor.build (e.g. 2.4.1)

npm checks and fixes the version of a particular package based on these characters

> **~** : major version is fixed, minor version is fixed, matches any build number

*e.g. : ~2.4.1 means it will check for 2.4.x where x is anything*

> **^** : major version is fixed, matches any minor version, matches any build number

*e.g. : ^2.4.1 means it will check for 2.x.x where x is anything*

Comment: I see 7 lines in this answer

Answer (score 25):

**Tilde ~** matches minor version, if you have installed a package that has 1.4.2 and after your installation, versions 1.4.3 and 1.4.4 are also available if in your package.json it is used as ~1.4.2 then npm install in your project after upgrade will install 1.4.4 in your project. But there is 1.5.0 available for that package then it will not be installed by ~. It is called minor version.

**Caret ^** matches major version, if 1.4.2 package is installed in your project and after your installation 1.5.0 is released then ^ will install major version. It will not allow to install 2.1.0 if you have **^1.4.2**.

**Fixed version** if you don't want to change version of package on each installation then used fixed version with out any special character e.g **"1.4.2"**

**Latest Version *** If you want to install latest version then only use * in front of package name.

Comment: This answer is misleading. SemVer clearly states, *A normal version number MUST take the form X.Y.Z [where] X is the major version, Y is the minor version, and Z is the patch version.*

Answer (score 18):

You probably have seen the tilde (~) and caret (^) in the package.json. What is the difference between them?

When you do npm install moment --save, It saves the entry in the package.json with the caret (^) prefix.

#### The tilde (~)

In the simplest terms, the tilde (~) matches the most recent minor version (the middle number). ~1.2.3 will match all 1.2.x versions but will miss 1.3.0.

#### The caret (^)

The caret (^), on the other hand, is more relaxed. It will update you to the most recent major version (the first number). ^1.2.3 will match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0.

Reference: https://medium.com/@Hardy2151/caret-and-tilde-in-package-json-57f1cbbe347b

Comment: Again, this answer is misleading. SemVer clearly states, *A normal version number MUST take the form X.Y.Z [where] X is the major version, Y is the minor version, and Z is the patch version.*

Answer (score 10):

### Terminology

[This is an oversimplification](https://semver.org/), but a semantic version consists of 3 parts: the major version, minor version, and patch version. For example, `1.2.3` has a major version of `1`, a minor version of `2`, and a patch version of `3`.

---

### Example<sup>*</sup>

For the examples below, assume that the current package is `app` and it depends
on `dep1`. The published versions of `dep1` are:

```json
{
  "dist-tags": { "latest": "1.2.2" },
  "versions": [
    "1.2.2",
    "1.2.1",
    "1.0.1",
    "1.0.0",
    "0.4.1",
    "0.4.0",
    "0.2.3",
    "0.2.0",
    "0.0.3",
    "0.0.2",
    "0.0.1"
  ]
}
```

### Tilde (~) Dependencies

I'll start with tilde because it's the most consistent. It will give you the latest patch version without changing the major or minor version.

| SemVer Range | Your `node_module` Version After `npm update --save` |
| --- | --- |
| ~1.2.1 | 1.2.2 |
| ~1.0.1 | 1.0.1 |
| ~1.0.0 | 1.0.1 |
| ~1.0.0 | 1.0.1 |
| ~0.4.1 | 0.4.1 |
| ~0.4.0 | 0.4.1 |
| ~0.2.3 | 0.2.3 |
| ~0.2.0 | 0.2.3 |
| ~0.0.3 | 0.0.3 |
| ~0.0.2 | 0.0.3 |
| ~0.0.1 | 0.0.3 |

### Caret (^) Dependencies >= v1.0.0 (a useful oversimplification)

Most *think* caret dependencies work like this: It will give you the latest minor version and patch version without changing the major version.

| SemVer Range | Your `node_module` Version After `npm update --save` |
| --- | --- |
| ^1.2.1 | 1.2.2 |
| ^1.0.1 | 1.2.2 |
| ^1.0.0 | 1.2.2 |
| ^1.0.0 | 1.2.2 |

*But that's not the whole picture*, this is only true when the major version is > 0. The next section explains how caret dependencies work regardless of the major version.

### Caret (^) Dependencies

Here's a more comprehensive explanation: Imagine the major version, minor version, and patch version are elements of an array (e.g., `[major, minor, patch]`). The caret dependency iterates the array until it finds the first non-zero, it "freezes" that non-zero in place, then it updates the *next* element(s) to the latest. In other words, assuming `x`, `y`, and `z` represent numbers greater than 0:

- `^x.y.z` will update `y` and `z` to the latest.
- `^0.y.z` will update `z` to the latest.
- `^0.0.z` won't update anything, because there is no element after `z`.

Let's see this in action:

| SemVer Range | Your `node_module` Version After `npm update --save` |
| --- | --- |
| ^1.2.1 | 1.2.2 |
| ^1.0.1 | 1.2.2 |
| ^1.0.0 | 1.2.2 |
| ^1.0.0 | 1.2.2 |
| ^0.4.1 | 0.4.1 |
| ^0.4.0 | 0.4.1 |
| ^0.2.3 | 0.2.3 |
| ^0.2.0 | 0.2.3 |
| ^0.0.3 | 0.0.3 |
| ^0.0.2 | 0.0.2 |
| ^0.0.1 | 0.0.1 |

<sup>*</sup>: This language was taken from https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-update#example and modified.

Comment: What would be the use-case of using ^ instead of ~?

Comment: @jumping_monkey [Assuming v0 packages are rare](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/7152#discussion_r1457024819) and all packages have a major, minor, and patch version number, I believe I could reword your question as, "What would be the use case of getting the latest minor & patch version instead of the latest patch version?" Both are non-breaking changes. A new minor version means that new features were added. A new patch version means bugs were fixed. Imagine this scenario:

Comment: @jumping_monkey You depend on Lib version `1.2.3`. Lib adds a non-breaking, new feature and becomes version `1.3.0`. Then somebody reports a security vulnerability that affects `1.2.3` *and* `1.3.0`. They fix this bug and become version `1.3.1`. If you only get new patch versions (i.e., `~1.2.3`), you will continue to use Lib with the security vulnerability (`1.2.3`). But if you get the new minors and patches (i.e., `^1.2.3`), you will get the latest secure version (`1.3.1`).  Let me know if that's confusing because this is pretty complex to describe in SO comments.

Comment: Awesome explanation Daniel! You are the best! ;-) — *As a result of that, you got +1 follower on github :-)*

Comment: Aw, thank you @jumping_monkey, I appreciate the kind words and feedback because I spent a lot of time thinking about how to write this answer.

Answer (score 8):

semver is separate in to 3 major sections which is broken by dots.

```
major.minor.patch
1.0.0
```

These different major, minor and patch are using to identify different releases.
tide (~) and caret (^) are using to identify which minor and patch version to be used in package versioning.

```
~1.0.1
 Install 1.0.1 or **latest patch versions** such as 1.0.2 ,1.0.5
^1.0.1
 Install 1.0.1 or **latest patch and minor versions** such as 1.0.2 ,1.1.0 ,1.1.1
```

Answer (score 7):

Related to this question you can review [Composer documentation on versions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md), but here in short:

- Tilde Version Range (**~**) - ~1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <**1.3.0**
- Caret Version Range (**^**) - ~1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <**2.0.0**

So, with **Tilde** you will get automatic updates of patches but minor and major versions will not be updated. However, if you use **Caret** you will get patches and minor versions, but you will not get major (breaking changes) versions.

Tilde Version is considered "safer" approach, but if you are using reliable dependencies (well-maintained libraries) you should not have any problems with Caret Version (because minor changes should not be breaking changes.

You should probably review [this stackoverflow post about differences between composer install and composer update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052195/what-are-the-differences-between-composer-update-and-composer-install).

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, per se, but an observation that seems to have been overlooked.

The description for caret ranges:

see: https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004

> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the
> [major, minor, patch] tuple.

Means that `^10.2.3` matches `10.2.3 <= v < 20.0.0`

I don't think that's what they meant. Pulling in versions 11.x.x through 19.x.x will break your code.

I think they meant `left most non-zero number field`.  There is nothing in SemVer that requires number-fields to be single-digit.

Comment: Just a note, the wording was fixed in the meantime: `Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero element`.

Answer (score 6):

For example for : ~1.8.0 you will match all of them 1.8.x versions, but you will lose 1.9.0 (This has been the default behavior).

For example for : ^1.8.0 you will be updated to the latest major version (the first issue). Any 1.x.x release including 1.9.0, but keeping the distance from version 2.0.0

Example 3.9.2:

```
Symbol     Dependency   Versions    Changes
tilde (~)   ~3.9.2        3.9.*      -bug fix

caret (^)   ^3.9.2        3.*.*      -backwards compatible new functionality 
                                     -old functionality deprecated, but operational
                                     -large internal refactor
                                     -bug fix
```

Answer (score 5):

Tilde `~` specifies to minor version releases

Caret `^` specifies to major version releases

For example, if package version is `4.5.2`, on update:

`~4.5.2` will install latest `4.5.x version (MINOR VERSION)`

`^4.5.2` will install latest `4.x.x version (MAJOR VERSION)`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answer is different from [the same answer posted 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json/22365742#22365742)?

Comment: Thanks for a great, short, and succinct answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The version number is in syntax which designates each section with different meaning. syntax is broken into three sections separated by a dot.

major.minor.patch
1.0.2

Major, minor and patch represent the different releases of a package.

npm uses the tilde (~) and caret (^) to designate which patch and minor versions to use respectively.

So if you see ~1.0.2 it means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest patch version such as 1.0.4. If you see ^1.0.2 it means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest minor or patch version such as 1.1.0.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answer is different from [the same answer posted 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json/22365742#22365742)?

Answer (score 4):

According to [semver docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver):

##### Tilde Ranges

Allows patch-level changes if a minor version is specified on the comparator. Allows minor-level changes if not.

*For eg*

- **~1.2.x** means >=1.2.0 <1.3.0
- **~1.2** means >=1.2.0 <1.3.0

##### Caret Ranges

Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions 0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X.

> Note: Many authors treat a 0.x version as if the x were the major
> "breaking-change" indicator.

*For eg*

- **^1.2.x** means >=1.2.0 <2.0.0
- **^1.2.3-beta.2** means >=1.2.3-beta.2 <2.0.0
- **^0.0.x** means >=0.0.0 <0.1.0
- **^0.0** means >=0.0.0 <0.1.0